# Get SCOPE_IDENTITY() in PHP

Tags: php, sql

Been trying to get the SCOPE_IDENTITY() (last ID inserted into DB) and store it as a variable in my PHP function.

Looked at all the answers I could possibly find on stackoverflow and I've still not managed to get there.

This is what I currently have:

```
// Confirm booking (update database) function
public function insert_userPost($conn) 
{
    // SQL INSERT command
    $sql = ("
           INSERT INTO userPost (content, submitted, emotion)
           VALUES ('$this->post', 'NOW()', '$this->emotion');
           ");
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
    {
        //echo "success";
        $sql = ("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as Id");
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        echo $result;
        //header('Location: feed.php?filter=all&page=1');
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Edit:

Also... in the construct I'm trying to pass the Id ($this->Id) in $this->post but it returns 0. I can see that this is due to the fact that I'm only setting $this->Id after the query goes through, thus returning 0 but I'm unsure how to proceed. Any suggestions?

```
// Construct
public function __construct($content, $emotion, $conn)
{
    $this->content = $content;
    $this->emotion = $emotion;
    $this->post = 
        "<div id=\'post\'>
            <div id=\'postContent\'>
                <p><b>I\'m $this->emotion because</b> $this->Id $this->content<span class=\'emot\'id=\'$this->emotion\'></span></p>
            </div>
            <div id=\'postInfo\'>
                <span class=\'postRelate\' title=\'Click to relate +1\'><p><b>relate</b> (0)</p></span>
                <span class=\'postSubmitted\'><p>submitted X minutes ago</p></span>
            </div>
        </div>";     
}

// Confirm booking (update database) function
public function insert_userPost($conn) 
{
    // SQL INSERT command
    $sql = ("INSERT INTO userPost (content, submitted, emotion)
             VALUES ('$this->post', NOW(), '$this->emotion')");
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
    {
        //echo "success";
        echo $this->Id = $conn->insert_id;
        //header('Location: feed.php?filter=all&page=1');
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `$conn->insert_id`? Querying twice is slower. [Ref](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: SQL. Sorry about the mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, your question is tagged `mysql`, but `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is a SQL Server function. That being said, your code contains [$conn->error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php), so I'm assuming that you're using MySQL with the MySQLi extension.

The MySQL equivalent to SQL Server's `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id). But calling it requires an extra query, which is cumbersome *and* slower.

Instead, your are advised to use the built-in MySQLi feature for this, the [$insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) property of your connection instance:

```
$id = $conn->insert_id;
```

Most SQL libraries have a built-in feature for this. If you were using PDO as your database abstraction layer, you could similarly use [PDO::lastInsertId()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php):

```
$id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

And this would work for both SQL Server and MySQL (and others).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error with the tags on my post. I'll make sure not to do that in the future. Your answer certainly helped, thanks again!

Comment: Your tags are perfectly fine, it's just the wording of the question that was somewhat confusing because of the reference to a function of another SQL vendor! Happy to help anyway.

Comment: Would you be able to look at my edit on my post? I'm more than happy to create a new question so you can get rep for it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see what the problem is just like that. You should indeed open a new question, as this is really a new one. This will attract new ideas from new people, and focus their attention on this very problem. By the way, you should really used [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.prepare.php) and bind parameters to them, instead of building a query string with built-in data as you do, which leaves you open to SQL injection, one of the most prevalent security holes in web applications.

Comment: I'll create a new question. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll certainly switch over to prepared statements in that case.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using MySQL then you need to use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, which is the SQLServer equivalent.

```
$sql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as Id";
```

You can also use the php property `$conn->insert_id`

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of Scope_Identity, you use it like this:

```
// Confirm booking (update database) function
public function insert_userPost($conn) 
{
    // SQL INSERT command
    $sql = ("
           INSERT INTO userPost (content, submitted, emotion)
           VALUES ('$this->post', 'NOW()', '$this->emotion');
           SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as Id
           ");
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
    {
        $result = $sql;
        echo $result;
        //header('Location: feed.php?filter=all&page=1');
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure on the PHP syntax, but the SQL portion matches my own usage.  There may also be an extraneous `;` at the end of the second line of your SQL query.