# Correct way/location to use Scope_Identity()

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv, scope-identity

I have an auto incrementing ID called deviceID in one of my fields. I was wanting to pass this to a session in php to use later on and was planning on using `scope_identity()` as I understand that this is the best way to get the current Primary key ID. However anytime I have attempted to use it I have had a error message saying that it is an undefined function. Here is my code so without the `scope_identity()`:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db.php';

$screenWidth = $_POST['screenWidth'];
$screenHeight = $_POST['screenHeight'];
$HandUsed = $_POST['HandUsed'];

$_SESSION["screenWidth"] = $screenWidth;
$_SESSION["screenHeight"] = $screenHeight;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $screenWidth = $_POST['screenWidth'];
    $screenHeight = $_POST['screenHeight'];
    $phoneType = $_POST['phoneName'];
    $HandUsed = $_POST['HandUsed'];
    $_SESSION["HandUsed"] = $HandUsed;
    $_SESSION["phoneName"] = $phoneType;

    echo 'hello';

    $sql = "
       INSERT INTO DeviceInfo (DeviceID, screenWidth, phoneType, screenHeight, HandUsed)
       VALUES ('$screenWidth','$phoneType', '$screenHeight', '$HandUsed')
       SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as DeviceID
    ";
    if (sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo ($sql);
        echo "New record has been added successfully !";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . ":-" . sqlsrv_errors($conn);
    }

    sqlsrv_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get SCOPE\_IDENTITY() in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009259/get-scope-identity-in-php)

Comment: You need to show us your code **with** `scope_identity()` so we can tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Hi, I tried the changes on the link SMor gave but to no luck - I added this into the edit, thanks

Comment: @b.man Can you post the exact error message? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix some issues in your code:

- The `INSERT` statement is wrong - you have five columns, but only four values in this statement. I assume, that `DeviceID` is an identity column, so remove this column from the column list.
- Use parameteres in your statement. Function `sqlsrv_query()` does both statement preparation and statement execution, and can be used to execute parameterized queries.
- Use `SET NOCOUNT ON` as first line in your statement to prevent SQL Server from passing the count of rows affected as part of the result set.
- `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is used correctly and it should return the expected `ID`. Of course, depending on the requirements, you may use `IDENT_CURRENT()`.

The following example (based on the code in the question) is a working solution:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $screenWidth = $_POST['screenWidth'];
    $phoneType = $_POST['phoneName'];
    $screenHeight = $_POST['screenHeight'];
    $HandUsed = $_POST['HandUsed'];

    $params = array($screenWidth, $phoneType, $screenHeight, $HandUsed);
    $sql = "
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        INSERT INTO DeviceInfo (screenWidth, phoneType, screenHeight, HandUsed)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS DeviceID
    ";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
    if ($stmt === false) {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . ": " . print_r(sqlsrv_errors());
        exit;
    }

    echo "New record has been added successfully !";
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row["DeviceID"];
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);

    sqlsrv_close($conn);
}
?>
```